# Svn: Merging with directory changes on both branch and trunk

Tags: svn, merge

I am trying to perform a merge of my svn branch to trunk but there have been changes made to the directory structure both on the trunk and on the branch.

The original directory structure at the point of branching is as follows:

> ```
> Main
> |---- Input
> |     |---- A
> |     |---- B, etc.
> |     ...
> |---- Output
>       |---- A
>       |---- B, etc.
>       ...
> ```

After branching, the directory structure on trunk changed to:

> ```
> Main
> |---- A
> |     |---- Input
> |     |---- Output
> |---- B, etc.
> ...
> ```

On the branch however, folder A was split into two separate folders so the directory structure became:

> ```
> Main
> |---- Input
>       |---- A_1
>       |---- A_2
>       |---- B, etc.
>       ...
> |---- Output
>       |---- A_2
>       |---- A_1
>       |---- B, etc.
>       ...
> ```

I would like to merge the branch to trunk so that it has the following structure and retains the history of all commits on the branch:

> ```
> Main
> |---- A_1
> |     |---- Input
> |     |---- Output
> |---- A_2
> |     |---- Input
> |     |---- Output
> |---- B, etc.
> ...
> ```

When I try to naively merge the branch to trunk I have tree conflicts with the Input and Output folders.  The svn status is:

> ```
> M      .
> !     C Input
> >   local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
> !     C Output
> >   local missing or deleted or moved away, incoming dir edit upon merge
> Summary of conflicts:
>   Tree conflicts: 2
> ```

It feels like I could merge just the A_1 and A_2 folders from my branch but they don't exist on trunk.  I have tried to create a new A_1/Input and A_2/Input folders on trunk and merge from Input/A_1 and Input/A_2 on my branch but I have issues with no common ancestry.  They obviously both stem from folder A but I can't work out how to get svn to take account of that.

Is there an easy/any way to do this?

I'm using svn, version 1.9.5

Comment: I find that SVN is not that robust on merging trunks or branches if the folders moved around. You can easily merge the moves from trunk to the branch or vice versa, but if the branch stays on one structure, the trunk moved folders, then SVN will not be able to "track" or "figure out" the moves. This feels like a shortcomming, but the current version of SVN can't do this yet. Using Subversion 1.14.2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading your Subversion to 1.10.x because this version has a new interactive conflict resolver: https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10#conflict-resolver. It might be helpful in these circumstances.